# Tomcat immediately undeploys .war after a successful deploy to webapps directory

Tags: java-8, war, octopus-deploy, tomcat-manager

I have an Octopus deployment plan using the Tomcat Manager step to deploy a .war to a linux box's instance of Tomcat. The deployment seems to succeed, but Tomcat will immediately undeploy it, causing a cycle of deployment attempts until Octopus gives up and fails the deployment.

In my catalina.out log on the target linux box, I see this:

```
07-Mar-2018 21:16:46.084 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-120] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/myWebApp.war has finished in 118,532 ms
07-Mar-2018 21:16:56.355 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-123] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/myWebApp]
```

There's 10 seconds in between deploying and undeploying. There's nothing in between these log lines to suggest why Tomcat decided to undeploy the webapps/myWebApp directory. What's strange is, after the final deployment attempt, the /myWebApp directory remains even though Octopus gives up and fails the deployment plan.

I'm wondering if anyone else has seen similar behavior while deploying .war files to Tomcat Manager, or if this behavior suggests a wonky config somewhere I don't know to look for.

Answer (score -1):

Today I had the same problem. I tried to deploy a third application on Tomcat and got the same log output as above (yes, even with a ten to twelve second delay).

After hours I finally found the solution: My new application was developed with Java 11 but Tomcat still runs on Java 8.

I'm sure there must be any exception during deployment but it was not logged to catalina.out. Even in other log files I didn't find any clues.